# Solid State - Radius Ratio rules

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

Why lithium salts crystallize in octahedral lattice , although radius ratio values are much below than expected ratio?

Comment: Because chemistry's "rules" are more "occasionally useful general guidelines", in spite of what secondary school chemistry teachers told you.

Comment: I second that. Also, there is no such thing as octahedral lattice. Also, there are quite a few lithium salts out there, and they crystallize in a variety of systems. If you mean halides, it would be better to say so.